# How to disable Kendo Datapicker and Dropdown which is inside a Kendo grid (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**Background**

I have a Kendo Grid with checkboxes, dropdownlist and datepicker. I am using row template functionality to add these controls on the grid. Below is the code for my grid.

**This is how I build my Kendo Grid**

```
 $("#firstReqGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 430,
    toolbar: ["save"],
    columns: [
        { field: "claimId", title: "ClaimID", width: 40 },
        { field: "lineCnt", title: "Lines", width: 10 },
        { title: "Med Requested", field: "medRecRequested", template: '<input type="checkbox" #= medRecRequested ? \'checked="checked"\' : "" # class="chkbx" />', width: 25, editable: function (e) { return false; } },
        { title: "EOB", field: "eobChk", template: '<input type="checkbox" #= eobChk ? \'checked="checked"\' : "" # class="chkbx" />', width: 25, editable: function (e) { return false; } },
        { title: "Claim", field: "clmChk", template: '<input type="checkbox" #= clmChk ? \'checked="checked"\' : "" # class="chkbx" />', width: 25, editable: function (e) { return false; } },
        { field: "MedRecRcvd", title: "Med Rec Rcvd", width: "30px", editor: medRecRcvdDropDownEditor, template: "#=MedRecRcvd.MedRecRcvdName#" },
        {
            field: "dateReceived", title:"Date Rcvd", format: "{0:dd MMM yyyy}", width: 30, editor: function (container, options) {
                var input = $("<input/>");
                input.attr("name", options.field);

                input.appendTo(container);

                input.kendoDatePicker({});
            }
        },           
        { title: "Memo", width: 40, template: '<input type="k-button" onclick="return addMemo(#=claimId#)" class="k-button" name="btnMemo" value="Memo" />' }],
    editable: true,
    dataBound: function (e) {
    /* This code disables all the checkboxes in the grid*/
        $("#firstReqGrid :input").attr("disabled", true);

        // var grid = $("#firstReqGrid").data("kendoGrid");
      //  var pageSizeDropDownList = grid.wrapper.children.find(".k-dropdown select").data("kendoDropDownList");
        //var dropDown = e.container.find("[data-role='dropdownlist']").data("kendoDropDownList");
        //if (dropDown) {
        //    dropDown.readonly();
        //}
     
    }
});
```

**What I am trying to achieve**

I want to be able to disable Datepicker and Dropdownlist if certain conditions are met. I was planning on checking for those "conditions" in the databound event of the grid and if conditions were met then disable datepicker and dropdownlist. I am aware of the datepicker.enable(false) event but in order to do that I need an id which I don't have in this instance. Same goes for dropdownlist list as well; I need an ID to disable the attribute. I need help on how to go about adding an ID for datepicker and dropdownlist with the code I have layed out. So that I can refer to that ID in grid databound event and turn on the disable property. Or if there is any other way I am open for suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want them disabled or do you just want to not allow the user to edit the record?

Comment: @David I want the datepicker and dropdown to be disabled. Which will basically not allow users to edit the record.

Comment: The reason I ask is because you can prevent the user from editing the record without having to worry about disabling the input. But if you specifically want to disable the input, that is a completely different matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the edit event ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/edit)) to do the following:

1. Do you custom business logic to determine if the input should be enabled/disabled
2. If disabling, then get the input
3. Then get the input's name
4. Do a conditional check to see if you want to get the `kendoDatePicker` or the `kendoDropDownList`
5. Call the `enabled` method with the result of the business logic.

Here is an example:

```js
edit: function(e) {
  if (SomeBusinessLogicHere()) {
    var input = e.container.find('input');
    var name = input.attr('name');
    if (name === 'my date field') {
      var datepicker = input.data('kendoDatePicker');
      datepicker.enable(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/uJidaKIf

FYI - If you wanted to prevent the editor from showing up in the first place you could handle the beforeEdit event ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/beforeedit)) and simply call `e.preventDefault()` if your business logic is true.

Comment: This worked wonderfully! I didn't know I could refer to datafields like this. Thanks a ton !!